Docker container runs differently on my local then it does is AWS
I'm using docker desktop on windows 11 to manage containers for my java web application.  I build container images on my local and can run them without issue.  When I push them to AWS and run them as a FARGATE service I get the following error when my application tries to send an email:

Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/activation/DataContentHandler
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2287)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:797)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1272)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1120)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)...

I'm assuming that my containers should run the same no matter what environment they run in.
Can somebody please explain to me why I am wrong in my assumption?
I really don't know what to try and change about my container because it works on my local.

Verify the image hashes are the same both locally and on AWS. Then verify you aren't using different environment variables or COMMAND overrides locally or on ECS.

hashes match and there are no command or environment variable overrides.  I am running docker desktop version 4.34.2 and AWS FARGATE Platform version 1.4.0.

To clarify, you don't specify a COMMAND or ENDPOINT in the ECS task definition? You let it use whatever is defined in the Dockerfile?

Correct, I'm not doing anything special when running the container in either environment.  It's like the class path in the container gets messed up when running in AWS.  There is quite a bit going on in this web application, and sending email seems to be the only thing that's not working.  I'll keep testing the app in AWS and see if anything else fails.

Your assumption is correct. If the class is found inside a locally running container the image must have it, also when running remotely. Hence doublecheck whether you really are running the same image.

Outside of running the tagged image that I just pushed to my amazon registry, then running it locally and comparing log output, I'm not really sure what else to double check.

Do not go for the tags - you might in both cases run 'latest'. Compare the image hash values. Eventually you need to tell Kubernetes to not cache the image or check for updates every time.

I suspected that this was a java dependency tree issue and bounced the idea off of some my coworkers.  Further analysis identified that our old ant build was packaging multiple versions of the same jar in the application deployment .war file causing a classic library collision issue.
So we decided to drop the old ant build process and use Maven. After building out a Maven pom file to support our legacy application we were able to build and deploy a new image to AWS and the issue went away.  I have seen class path issues like this in the past when running the same java application in windows and linux before, but expected a containerized deployment to mitigate the possibility of this occurring.  Boy was I wrong.
